# forcasting to filling missing values in time series

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data

I have many time series objects that look like

```
     Jan Feb Mar Apr ......
2007  1   2    3  NA 
2008  3   4    5  7
2009  4   2   NA  1   
  .
  .
```

I want to forecast to fill in the missing data with rforecast, by actively looking for the NAs and filling them in with the forcasted values, like for example using jan,feb, mar of 2007 and  forecast april then use the years 2007,2008 and then jan and feb of 2009 to forcast march and so on. Is there a way thats does not involve a complicated mess of for loops?

Comment: The zoo package has quite a few functions few NA filling of zoo time series: `library(zoo); ls(pattern = "^na[.]", "package:zoo")` .

Comment: I used ts smooth, but then because i wanted to do Singular spectral analysis on the time series, I used a package called simsalabim, which incorporates a gap filler method

Comment: How do you forecast the value of apr 2007 using jan feb and mar? Use the mean?

Answer (score 1):

Forecasting does not make to much sense in this case.
As mentioned in the comments, this would mean a forecast of april 2007 using only jan,feb,mar.

Better in this case would be using a proper time series imputation method.

Which can be found in these packages:

- **imputeTS** (na_kalman() and others)
- **zoo**  (na.StructTS())
- **forecast** (na.interp())

If you insist in forecasting, then a forecasting/backcasting combination would be the best option. (see also https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/213975/92235 )